# how to compare 2 url's ignoring s in https://

Tags: python-3.x, http, url, https

I want to compare 2 url's a="https://example.com/rghj.mp3" and b="http://example.com/rghj.mp3" . I want to make a condition which ignores the s in https and compares these 2 url's and evaluates to True.What is the best way to do that ? I am trying to do a.split("//:")[1]==b.split("//:")[1].Does this code break for any url format ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Thanks that's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
a.replace("https://","http://") == b.replace("https://","http://")
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to take a more robust approach.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
a_url = urlparse(a)
b_url = urlparse(b)
match = a_url.netloc == b_url.netloc
```

Comment: yeah that works for above ..what about for url like this http://audio.simplecast.com/rghj.mp3  ? wanted to be more general

Comment: You mean for the quick and dirty version? Then you can do `a.replace("https://","").replace("http://","")`. I don't suggest you head down this rabbit hole of what-ifs, and use urlparse.

Comment: ok thank you . The netloc you mentioned above gives only the middle part. how to get the entire part except scheme without joining different parts ?